AWS Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer scales-in instance even thoguh there are still async processes running on it
I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk worker environment which processes some data in Node.js based on SQS messages or Cron-Jobs.
One of the Cron-Jobs is running a main process (currently taking 20~ minutes) which launches 0-N async "child-processes".
The child processes have a worst case runtime of one hour with regularly sleeps of 1 minute in it.
In the logs I found some those child processes never finishing, in a FIFO manner, so it seems like this is caused by the Load Balancer shutting down instances where those processes are still running. Those processes are also not taking up a lot of CPU because of the sleeps, which may contribute to the issue, since the load balance measurement works with the CPU metric.
Is there a simple, if possible "on-instance" way to prevent the Load Balancer shutting the instance down during the process runtime?

First a bit of terminology clarification. The load balancer does not handle instance scaling. It just distributes traffic to your instances. The Auto-Scaling Group is what handles instance scaling, and adding or removing instances from the load balancer's target group.
AWS Auto-Scaling groups have the ability to notify your EC2 instances when they are scheduled for termination due to scale-in events. Your EC2 instances can use Termination lifecycle hooks to postpone the termination event until they have completed their current task.
